# How to fix iOS Extension Subquery?

Tags: ios8, ios-extensions

I have this query in `info.plist` of extension:

```
SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text").@count >= 1).@count >= 1
```

Here count >=1 means more than 1 file can be import using extension. I want something like count<=10 but < is showing error.

How < can be implemented here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer myself.

since this in xml tags for < we have symbolise it with <
So say if i to limit the max image count to 5 i will perfrom like this:

```
SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem,
 SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ANY 
 $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO 
 "public.plain-text").@count &lt;= 5).@count >= 1
```